# How to import this library to Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am trying this:
https://github.com/pelotoncycle/weberknecht

To the latest Android Studio.

Problem is that there is no gradle file with it that many tutorials around say you need it to import?

Can anyone tell me how to import this library so I can use it in my android project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just download all the sources from [this folder](https://github.com/pelotoncycle/weberknecht/tree/master/src/de/roderick/weberknecht) and put them into your project, there are not that many of them.

Comment: What about the files from: https://github.com/pelotoncycle/weberknecht/tree/master/src/net/iharder

I assume not having this will cause issues?

Comment: @user1861967 yeah, that `Base64` source file is used in [`WebSocketHandshake`](https://github.com/pelotoncycle/weberknecht/blob/1350190a1d3d82ec34b412f05c154e26306de01b/src/de/roderick/weberknecht/WebSocketHandshake.java), so you'll have to add that one too. Sorry, missed it. And don't forget to place them properly in your project directory so the packages will correspond to their pathes.

Comment: Ah well, I just threw this entire SRC folder (https://github.com/pelotoncycle/weberknecht/tree/master/src)  where all the the .java files are for my project, but I still can't access any of the files? Am I missing some step here?

Comment: @user1861967 are the pathes exactly the same as on Github? Then just add `import de.roderick.weberknecht.<name of used class>;` in the beginning of the source file where you're going to use it. Try restarting the Studio if it doesn't help.

Comment: Ah got it, you rock :)